Recovering Image Paths or Deployed Code from Firebase Hosting
I have a web app deployed to Firebase. I no longer have access to the original code and I believe it is not straight forward / possible to recover the deployed code from Firebase?
There is an image on the app and all I want to do is to try to find the path of the image. However, when I try to open the "inspect element" window, I can't select the image of interest, as the whole pane is highlighted and is called "fit-glass-pane" or something. Similarly when I try to look through the code to find an "img" there don't seem to be any.
Is there any other way I can find the path where the image lives? Or better yet, can I somehow download the code currently deployed on Firebase?
